# What do you call someone who's involved in a project (non-leading role)

Tags: meaning, vocabulary

We currently have two roles for our project, namely:

- project manager
- `someone who is involved', ie. regular worker/employee

but I'm not really satisfied with worker. What do you usually call someone who works on a project within a team?

Comment: How about a (project) team member?

Comment: That would work, though I was hoping for something more precise/succinct. Would `participant' be appropriate in this context? The idea is that these people will be assigned tasks and will be expected to complete them. So the word would have to reflect the notion of being *active*. 'Asset' could be one word but that might hurt some feelings.

Comment: As long as you cannot be more specific about the tasks, it is hard to find a more specific word. Are all team members supposed to execute any task the project manager gives them? Or do they have several different roles again (a programmer, a tester, a designer)?

Comment: They are expected to execute any task assigned by the PM. Tasks are diverse and could be testing, developing, reviewing, documenting, benchmarking, and so on, which is why I tried to keep my question as generic as possible.

Comment: As they "participate" in the project, you could use participants, but I really think "team member" covers your needs. I have described myself as such on occasion, and I never had the feeling that describing myself as a member of the "quick projects team" would imply impassivity on my side.

Comment: Thanks for your input. My only concern is the redundancy of saying 'team member' in a system that already manages what it calls 'teams' and their 'members' with their roles. I'm really looking for a word that evokes something akin to 'stakeholders'.

Comment: If this is a true project then no one is actually working on anything.

Comment: @RyeBread: This is a true project. And so far, you're quite right :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might consider Contributor if Team Member isn't working for you.

Comment: 7 years on and I still think that Contributor or Member are still the best options. Cheerio!

Answer (score 4):

A project would have:

1. A Project Manager
2. Fellow Members (or simply) 'Associates' (or) 'Fellows'

If you are against using 'team member' as a designation, I think the above terms should suffice as a clear, simple way to suggest hierarchy while denoting each person's interest in and commitment toward the project.

Other alternatives:

- Project Co-workers
- Project Peers
- Project Partners
- Collaborators
- Affiliates

These are all good terms to denote, as you say, a 'stakeholder's' position in a project.

If you wanted a more-casual, less-formal term, you could try coining one yourself (tailor-made for your particular project) and it should work just fine - Example: Project Mates

Comment: Thanks, I could have accepted your answer as well. I think I'll go with a mixture of your suggestion and @Polymath's, hence choosing **Fellow contributors**. Mates is too informal (these are people from their mid 30s to late 50s with little experience with one another).

Comment: I think fellow contributors is an excellent choice. I've used it myself.

Comment: @Polymath: it does sound just about right, doesn't it.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the role of the members in the project.

- Use the same job titles, such as **Developer**, **Artist**, **Quality Assurance** if the team member is solely doing one job or one type of task in the project.
- **Team member** if the person doing it is not assigned a specific role.
- Current job titles with prefix 'Lead' - **Lead Developer**, **Lead Artist**, **Lead Modeller**, **Lead Environment Artist**, for supervisory roles one level below Project Manager.

Answer (score 1):

*Team member* is the term typically used in projectized organizations unless they have an elevated level of authority. See, for example, [this page](https://www.pmiwdc.org/article/karen-davey-winter/team-building-and-development-matrix-environment) from the Project Management Institute.

[image]

Comment: You're taking this to a whole new level. I'd have chosen *team member* if it didn't conflict with the system's own terminology.

Comment: There's a book called PMBOK (Project Management Body Of Knowledge). If you can scarf one of those from someone (anyone with a PMP credential should have one) it may help.

Answer (score 0):

"Team member" is far and away the most commonly used term in business for what you are suggesting.

(See as a reference books by any well-known business leader, such as Stephen R. Covey, and you will notice the commonality of the term, implying that its meaning is widely understood.)

Answer (score 0):

What about "delegate"?

Does that work?

> **Delegate**
>   *noun*
>
> delegate; plural noun: delegates
>
> /ˈdɛlɪgət/
>
> 1. a person sent or authorized to represent others, in particular an elected representative sent to a conference.
>
> "congress delegates rejected the proposals"
>
> **Synonyms**:
>   representative, envoy, emissary, commissioner, agent, deputy, commissary; spokesperson, spokesman, spokeswoman; 
>   ambassador, plenipotentiary; 
>   messenger, go-between, proxy; depute; nuncio; 
>   archaiclegate
>
> "delegates from the UN"
>
> 2. a member of a committee
>
> *verb*
>
> delegate; 3rd person present: delegates; past tense: delegated; past participle: delegated; gerund or present participle: delegating
>
> /ˈdɛlɪgeɪt/
>
> 1. entrust (a task or responsibility) to another person, typically one who is less senior than oneself.
>
> "she must delegate duties so as to free herself for more important tasks"
>
> **Synonyms:** assign, entrust, give, pass on, hand on/over, turn over, consign, devolve, depute, transfer

Comment: 'Delegate' has a strong connotation of representing someone or something in my view.

Comment: This is a good answer, but I would recommend that you link to the dictionary definition rather than copy/pasting or typing it out.

Answer (score -1):

Personnel: "1.  persons employed in any work, enterprise, service, establishment, etc. see also materiel"

Answer (score -2):

How about a "participant" or a "consulted".

Comment: *Participant* is what I would use, but *a consulted* (if it exists) would be somebody outside the team whose views are taken into account.

Comment: Resp. _consulted_: Granted, I don't know if that word is used elsewhere than business (see "RACI"). But to my understanding, the question didn't say anything about whether or not this person is from within a company etc. or from outside.

Comment: I did say *outside the team*, as opposed to OPs 'within aq team'. But perhaps we should take this to chat.